# VBA Email Users Only Once

Tags: excel, vba, email

I work with a program that allows instructors to submit referrals for college students who are struggling academically.  We then reach out to students and suggest resources that may benefit them.  I'm using a spreadsheet to track our call outcomes with students and need to be able to automate follow-up emails to faculty alerting them to the outcome of our calls.  I'm using the following code to do that, but every time I run the code it will email all faculty on the list.

Is there a code to attach to the bottom of this to identify when an email has been sent at the end of each row?  If so, is there a code to have Excel/Outlook only send emails to users who have not been emailed?  Does this make sense?

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
Sub SendEMail()
    Dim Email As String, Subj As String
    Dim Msg As String, URL As String
    Dim r As Integer, x As Double
    For r = 2 To 4 'data in rows 2-4
'       Get the email address
        Email = Cells(r, 9)

'       Message subject
        Subj = "Success Connect Referral Update"

'       Compose the message
        Msg = ""
        Msg = Msg & "Hello "
        Msg = Msg & "Student Success Center Peer Callers attempted to reach out to: "
        Msg = Msg & Cells(r, 1).Text & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        Msg = Msg & "The following interaction occured: "
        Msg = Msg & Cells(r, 7).Text & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf


        Msg = Msg & "Mike Dial" & vbCrLf
        Msg = Msg & "Coordinator of Early Intervention" & vbCrLf
        Msg = Msg & "Student Success Center"

'       Replace spaces with %20 (hex)
        Subj = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Subj, " ", "%20")
        Msg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Msg, " ", "%20")

'       Replace carriage returns with %0D%0A (hex)
        Msg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Msg, vbCrLf, "%0D%0A")
'       Create the URL
        URL = "mailto:" & Email & "?subject=" & Subj & "&body=" & Msg

'       Execute the URL (start the email client)
        ShellExecute 0&, vbNullString, URL, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus

'       Wait two seconds before sending keystrokes
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Application.SendKeys "%s"
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells(r, x).Value = "Sent"` where `x` is the first blank column (I don't know how many columns you use).

Answer (score 0):

Add a new "E-Mailed" column, say column 10 (J) after the email address.

When the email is sent set the cells value to something, check it the next time round.

```
For r = 2 To 4 'data in rows 2-4
    if Cells(r, 10).Value = "" then
'       Get the email address
        Email = Cells(r, 9)

        .. rest of code ..

        Cells(r, 10).Value = "Sent: " & Now
    end if
Next r
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sendkeys method is really bad and should be avoided. Given that you have both Excel and Outlook, you can develop a VBA procedure from within Excel that will scan your columns in Excel and send the email based on a certain criteria.